# How to fix "Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; " using Spring-mvc?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have a crash when I tried to send messages with a web application using spring-MVC and an XML configuration file.

The application seemed to work but when i hit the button to send the message I faced the following nested exception:

Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;nested exception is:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;nested exception is:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I used tomcat 7 and Eclipse to run this project.

I changed the bean in the configuration.file and changed the Gmail security configuration but I still have the same problem.

EmailController.java:

```
package com.jcg.spring.mvc.email;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class EmailController {

    static String emailToRecipient, emailSubject, emailMessage;
    static final String emailFromRecipient ="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    static ModelAndView modelViewObj;

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSenderObj;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "emailForm"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showEmailForm(ModelMap model) {
        modelViewObj = new ModelAndView("emailForm");
        return  modelViewObj;       
    }

    // This Method Is Used To Prepare The Email Message And Send It To The Client
    @RequestMapping(value = "sendEmail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView sendEmailToClient(HttpServletRequest request, final @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile attachFileObj) {

        // Reading Email Form Input Parameters      
        emailSubject = request.getParameter("subject");
        emailMessage = request.getParameter("message");
        emailToRecipient = request.getParameter("mailTo");

        // Logging The Email Form Parameters For Debugging Purpose
        System.out.println("\nReceipient?= " + emailToRecipient + ", Subject?= " + emailSubject + ", Message?= " + emailMessage + "\n");

        mailSenderObj.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {

                MimeMessageHelper mimeMsgHelperObj = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");             
                mimeMsgHelperObj.setTo(emailToRecipient);
                mimeMsgHelperObj.setFrom(emailFromRecipient);               
                mimeMsgHelperObj.setText(emailMessage);
                mimeMsgHelperObj.setSubject(emailSubject);

            }
        });
        System.out.println("\nMessage Send Successfully.... Hurrey!\n");

        modelViewObj = new ModelAndView("success","messageObj","Thank You! Your Email Has Been Sent!");
        return  modelViewObj;   
    }
}
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
  <!-- Spring Email Sender Bean Configuration -->

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
        <property name="username" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
        <property name="password" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">465</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Spring Mvc Email Example</display-name>

    <!-- Spring Configuration - Processes Application Requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>   

    <!-- Welcome File List -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>emailForm.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

log :

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers

....

DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP l***********.22 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587


EHLO ********PC
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [**********]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```

Could you help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: you should try the port changing to 587 in servlet xml

Answer (score 0):

`<property name="port" value="587" />`

change to

`<property name="port" value="465" />`